# Unable to mount NTFS partition from sata disk over usb adapter

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ntfs, sata

I'm trying to recover data from a sata disk using a sata to usb adapter. The disk was working fine in my windows laptop until the motherboard died.
The drive is properly detected when I insert the usb plug. This is the ouput from dmesg:

```
[246601.976098] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[246602.108959] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[246602.108971] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[246602.108979] usb 2-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[246602.108985] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[246602.108991] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000001D91881
[246602.109891] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[246602.111296] scsi13 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[246603.108783] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD32 00BPVT-22ZEST0        PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[246603.111462] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[246603.117957] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 78142806 4096-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[246603.119741] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[246603.119745] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[246603.120964] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[246603.120968] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[246603.122528] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 78142806 4096-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[246603.123822] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[246603.123828] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[246605.903375]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
[246605.903495] sdc: p3 size 4781359104 extends beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
[246605.904707] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 78142806 4096-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[246605.905577] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[246605.905584] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[246605.906619]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
[246605.906712] sdc: p3 size 4781359104 extends beyond EOD, truncated
[246605.908122] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 78142806 4096-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[246605.949247] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[246605.949250] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[246605.949263] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

I can also see the drive and its partitions in fdisk:

```
root@samsung:/mnt# fdisk -l

...

Disk /dev/sdc: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4864 cylinders, total 78142806 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6d92112a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    27265023   109051904   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdc2   *    27265024    27469823      819200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3        27469824   625139711  2390679552    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

but when I try to mount the partitions (no matter which one) I get an error:

```
root@samsung:/mnt# mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc2 old_disk
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Somehow the NTFS seems to be broken on all partitions. Any ideas how I could get my data back?

I also tried looking at the drive with GParted and it wouldn't recognize any partitions on the drive at all.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you try this? http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271 If it works for you I can sum it up in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was using testdisk to copy the files I needed from the old disk. Testdisk was apparently able to read the partitions just fine.

I had to use the most rececent version of testdisk (7.0) though instead of 6.14 which kept crashing when I tried to read the most important of the paratitions.